# Inserting complex json object into a sql schema

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a json object of the form

```
{   
    "483329": 
    {"Dairy_free": false,
     "Gluten_free": true,
     "Vegetarian": false,
     "Vegan": false, 
     "ketagonic": false},

     "577539": 
     {"Dairy_free": true,
      "Gluten_free": false, 
      "Vegetarian": true, 
      "Vegan": true, 
      "ketagonic": false}
}
```

Where the schema is

```
    | id | Dairy_free | Gluten_free | Vegetarian | Vegan|  ketagonic|
    +----+------------+-------------+------------+------+-----------+
```

Is there a way without re-generating the json to insert the json object to mysql, using mysqlcursors?

```
sql_insert = INSERT INTO allergies VALUES (Default, %s %s %s %s %s);"
cursor = config.cursor
for obj in json_objects <---- this is where I need to transfer to suitable object
try:
    affected_count = cursor.execute(sql_insert, (object))
    config.dbconnection.commit()
except Exception as e:
    print e
```

Comment: what interval is the JSON data being pulled at. Are you making any get requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can use executemany followed from [MySQLdb User's Guide](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)

```
data = list(map(lambda x: tuple(x.values()), json_objects.values()))
# [(False, True, False, False, False), (True, False, True, True, False)]

c.executemany(
    """INSERT INTO allergies VALUES (Default, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)""",
    data
)
```